# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException due to mapping class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, sqlexception

Exception caused by mapping class=Student

**Student.java**
This is entity class with Jpa annotations

```java
package org.jsp.dto;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String add;
    private long phone;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAdd() {
        return add;
    }

    public void setAdd(String add) {
        this.add = add;
    }

    public long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

}
```

**student.hbm.xml**
This is hibernate mapping file.

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.jsp.dto.Student" table="hib_student">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="identity"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name"></property>
        <property name="add" column="address"></property>
        <property name="phone" column="phone"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**
This is hibernate config file

Here if mapping class="org.jsp.dto.Student"  changed to mapping resource=student.hbm.xml  it works fine.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hib_student</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="org.jsp.dto.Student" />
        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Controller**
Here I am trying to create table using `buildSessionFactory` Interface of hibernate.

```java
package org.jsp.Controller;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;



public class CreateTable {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration con=new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory sf=con.buildSessionFactory();
    
}
}
```

Exception due to <mapping class="org.jsp.dto.Student" /> tag

```
May 22, 2023 5:45:57 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.14.Final
May 22, 2023 5:45:58 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
May 22, 2023 5:45:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
May 22, 2023 5:45:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hib_student]
May 22, 2023 5:45:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
May 22, 2023 5:45:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
May 22, 2023 5:45:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
May 22, 2023 5:45:59 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
May 22, 2023 5:46:00 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@5339bbad] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: 
    
    create table Student (
       id integer not null auto_increment,
        add varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        phone bigint not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
May 22, 2023 5:46:00 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table Student (
       id integer not null auto_increment,
        add varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        phone bigint not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table Student (
       id integer not null auto_increment,
        add varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        phone bigint not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:728)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
    at org.jsp.Controller.CreateTable.main(CreateTable.java:12)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        phone bigint not null,
 ' at line 3
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

May 22, 2023 5:46:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

But it works fine if change it to resource=hibernate.cfg.xml but I want to make it work with entity class.

Comment: Can you modify the property name from `add` to `address` and try again? `add` is a keyword in MySQL like `ADD CONSTRAINT`.